# Discord python unban member

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Ok, my ban command works `ban(member)`, however when doing the same except using `unban(member)` the output is always that the user wasn't found.
Here's the code of the ban command, what's the correct usage of the unban command?

```
@commands.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(self, ctx, member:discord.Member=None):
    """Bans a member."""
    if not member:
        await self.bot.say("Who would you like me to ban, {0.mention}?".format(ctx.message.author))
        pass
    await self.bot.ban(member)
    await self.bot.say(f"{member.mention} got banned, what a shame...")
    print(colored('moderation.clf: ', 'blue'), colored('Banned member', 'white'))
```

Comment: `unban` takes a `User`, not a `Member`.  This is because when you ban someone from the server, they aren't a `Member` anymore.  You need to get their `User` object instead.

Comment: Ok! does the same happen with `await server_voice_state(user=member, deafen=True)` and `await server_voice_state(user=member, mute=True)`?

Comment: [`server_voice_state`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.server_voice_state) has no `user` parameter.  It has a `member` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since members represent users inside a server you can't have a member instance for a user that is currently banned. You have to use the `User` instance which is not server-specific to unban, for example `await self.bot.unban(server, user)` where server is of type `discord.Server` and user of type `discord.User`.